# Geb + Groovy select custom element with a dash in the attribute name

Tags: groovy, ui-automation, geb

I am trying to use the Geb jQuery selector on the following element:

```
<li data-title="Something"><'li>
```

I have tried the following:

```
//1
$("li", "data-title": "Something")
//2
$("li", data-title: "Something")
```

But neither work. Is this possible?

Comment: You're using `$("li", "data-title": "Some value")` yeah? Not `Something`?

Comment: I just wrote a quick check in Geb's codebase to confirm that these kind of attributes can be used to select elements with. Are you sure that the element exists in the page when you're trying to select it? Seeing an attribute name prefixed with `data-` makes me believe that you're using some kind of js framework for single page applications, is that right?

Comment: @tim_yates yes we are using a MVC framework, AngularJS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use the CSS selector for a custom attribute for this:

```
$("li[data-title='Something']")
```